# IE11 problems with position fixed dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, css-position, internet-explorer-11, fixed

I have been struggling with this for hours. I have a series of problems related with z-index, position:fixed in IE11. I have tried -ms-device-fixed but nothings seems to resolve this really weird issue. Part of the dropdown is not visible like you can see on the image.

```
.ms-webpart-zone.ms-fullWidth .ms-webpartzone-cell {
 display: block;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: visible;
 min-height: 220px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}
```

Dropdown CSS:

```
position:-ms-device-fixed!important;
z-index:20;
top: 10px;
position: fixed;
visibility: visible;
left: 88px;
width: 226px;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: To me looks like there is a hard coded height/width somewhere. That seems like the only reason why it would be clipped where it is. But also, are you 100% sure that position fixed is what you want here?

Comment: Actually not is absolutely not what i want BUT unfortunately its sharepoint dealing with a really shitty html structure where css is coming from everywhere, so basically i'm just trying to fix the most horrible things that wont let the final user work, is mostly about that. Thanks @user875234, still i'm not really sure what's the problem with the height, when i dont use position fixed dropdowns seems right but they wont overflow the div.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using `position: expression(fixed);`
2. Try using `position: relative;` on the parent element and `position: absolute;` on your caption. This is cross-browser.